# Convert string with preg_replace in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this string

```
$string = "some words and then #1.7 1.7 1_7 and 1-7";
```

and I would like that **#1.7/1.7/1_7 and 1-7** to be replaced by **S1E07**.
Of course, instead of "1.7" is just an example, it could be "3.15" for example.

I managed to create the regular expression that would match the above 4 variants

```
/\#\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}/
```

but I cannot figure out how to use preg_replace (or something similar?) to actually replace the matches so they end up like **S1E07**

Comment: You need to provide more explicit information regarding the format of possible inputs, and exactly how those inputs effect the output.  Will it always be `1` and `7`, or could it be different numbers (or different length of numbers, i.e. something like `23.456`)? Is the output based on those values, and if so, is the `7` supposed to be padding with a leading `0` when it's less than 10?

Comment: numbers can be from 1 to 99 so it can be 1.1 to 99.99. padding would be nice but not a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback` if you need to pad `0` if the number less than `10`.

```
$string = "some words and then #1.7 1.7 1_7 and 1-7";
$string = preg_replace_callback('/#?(\d+)[._-](\d+)/', function($matches) {
  return 'S'.$matches[1].'E'.($matches[2] < 10 ? '0'.$matches[2] : $matches[2]);
}, $string);
```

Comment: Thank you! Your regular expression is surely more elegant than mine and the results are those expected the only thing is that it will also match stuff like _1999.12_ which I wouldn't want. I tried with \d{1,2} but I would get back _19S99E12_

Comment: Using word boundaries `\b` you should be able to achieve this. Check my answer out. It's tested and works.

Comment: yes, your answer works and is almost perfect it is just that if I use `\b` this way `/\b#?(\d{1,2})[._-](\d{1,2})/` I'll get **#S1E07**

Comment: My bad put the word boundary after the `#?` and you're all set. Like `#?\b(\d...`

Answer (score 2):

You could use this simple string replace:

```
preg_replace('/#?\b(\d{1,2})[-._](\d{1,2})\b/', 'S${1}E${2}', $string);
```

But it would not yield zero-padded numbers for the episode number:

```
// some words and then S1E7 S1E7 S1E7 and S1E7
```

You would have to use the evaluation modifier:

```
preg_replace('/#?\b(\d{1,2})[-._](\d{1,2})\b/e', '"S".str_pad($1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."E".str_pad($2, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)', $string);
```

...and use str_pad to add the zeroes.

```
// some words and then S01E07 S01E07 S01E07 and S01E07
```

If you don't want the season number to be padded you can just take out the first str_pad call.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you want it to...

```
/\#?([0-9]+)[._-]([0-9]+)/
```

In other words...

- `\#?` - can start with the `#`
- `([0-9]+)` - capture at least one digit
- `[._-]` - look for one `.`, `_` or `-`
- `([0-9]+)` - capture at least one digit

And then you can use this to replace...

```
S$1E$2
```

Which will put out `S` then the first captured group, then `E` then the second captured group

Answer (score 1):

You need to put brackets around the parts you want to reuse ==> capture them. Then you can access those values in the replacement string with `$1` (or ${1} if the groups exceed 9) for the first group, `$2` for the second one...

The problem here is that you would end up with $1 - $8, so I would rewrite the expression into something like this:

```
/#?(\d{1,2})[._-](\d{1,2})/
```

and replace with

```
S${1}E${2}
```

I tested it on [writecodeonline.com](http://writecodeonline.com/php/):

```
$string = "some words and then #1.7 1.7 1_7 and 1-7";
$result = preg_replace('/#?(\d{1,2})[._-](\d{1,2})/', 'S${1}E${2}', $string);
```